# Converting HSRP to GLBP with 2 ISP

Tags: hsrp

[image]

In this lap, I configured HSRP to make the R2 is backup of R1, but I want to change HSRP to GLBR that is using load balance that is meaning R1 and R2 will operate in the same time with 2 lines (between R1&ISP and between R2&ISP) with 2 ISPs. Is that meaning Now the speed of my connection between LAN branch and HQ is improved ????
and if (no) how to use the 2 lines in the same time to improve my speed?

Comment: Have you read the documentation? https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/ios-nx-os-software/ip-services/product_data_sheet0900aecd803a546c.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your diagram, you have one PC.  GLBP will not help you there.

If you have many PCs, GLBP *might* help assuming:

1. If your routers are performing NAT, they are using separate address space.
2. There is sufficient bandwidth at your HQ for the entire load of this site.

Comment: Thank you for your replying. And yes I have a lot of devices in this branch But I don't have NAT already, I use BGP protocol between LAN and HQ through a frame-relay tunnel, That may change anything ??